# Take multiple pictures instead of making a video (Samsung Galaxy S10e)

Tags: camera, android-10, samsung-galaxy-s-10

I have a Samsung Galaxy S10e (Android 10) and I can't take pictures fast after each other when I holding down the shutter button. It will always take a video.

In the begin, it was well possible to do it with my smartphone. I can't find a setting to enable it. Is that option removed?

**Update:** I can only find a setting for `Swipe shutter button to edge to`.

Answer (score 1):

In the camera settings, look for `Hold Shutter button to`. You should see 3 options: Take a picture, Take the burst shot and Create GIF. Select Take the burst shot.

This [article](https://gadgetguideonline.com/s10/galaxy-s10-camera-settings-explained/) explains the difference between the 3 options.

> - Take a picture. Essentially, it is identical to the single tap gesture.
> - Take the burst shot. You are using the Galaxy S10 burst mode. All photos taken in the burst mode will be always saved in the phone storage even you set the storage as the SD card.
> - Create GIF. Galaxy S10 camera will take a series of photos and saved them as one GIF animation file. Please note, the resolution of the GIF animation is 480*640 (VGA) only. You do not have the option to change the resolution for the GIF.

Comment: I can't find that option. See my questio for more info.